# Is there any way to reduce the size of python 2.7.6 package (unnessary folders or not needed folders or less needed folders inside python package))

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7

I am building a `.exe`. Python is called from my `.exe` and I have included the python package along with that for python to work. I find the package is of high size. Is there any way to reduce the python package size .

Comment: You can remove various pieces of the python distribution tree if you don't need them, but you're the arbiter of what you need and don't need.  For example if you don't need distutils, you can remove the entire folder from the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would suggest going through the folder and cherry picking what you don't use. Some that might be good to get rid of :

- `/Doc`, which contains the Python documentation for your version
- `/Scripts`, which has stuff like `pip` in it
- `/tcl`, which contains the several megabytes of data for Python-Tcl interfaces to work
  . You only need this if you're using Tkinter.
- anything in `/Lib` that you don't import. That's where the standard modules are stored
- `/include`, which stores the Python-C interface*
- `/Tools/demo`, which contains examples of python

*Only delete this if you aren't using any C-based 3rd party library's. If you are unsure, don't risk it.

Comment: I am not supposed to do trial and error method ( deleting folders and checking). It may create issue.Is there any way to find only  the (neccessary folders or files) to run the python files

Comment: @KawinAnto I added some explanations of what each folder is

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it reduced the file size to some extent.Thankyou